# How to press multiple keys at once using webbot Browser on Python

Tags: python, webbot

I am using Browser from webbot to do some things on a browser.
However, I ran into a problem when I am trying to press 2 keys at once such that key number 1 is pressed down, then key number 2 is pressed down then lifted up, then key number 1 is lifted back up.
For instance, when there is text, and you are trying to select all of it by pressing CTRL + A or copying with CTRL + C.

I currently have:

```
from webbot import Browser
web = Browser()

web.go_to(any_website)
web.press(web.Key.CONTROL) + web.type('a')
```

However, this presses and lifts back up the CTRL button before it presses button A.

How do I solve this, such that it presses down the CTRL button, presses and releases the A button, then releases the CTRL button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
web.press(web.Key.CONTROL + 'a')
```

Found documentation about webbot, here's the https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/webbot/latest/webbot.pdf

Search for:
Press any special key or a key combination involving Ctrl , Alt , Shift

Comment: Hello @CEO1111, this should work now. Amended answer :)

Comment: I had the same document open but I guess I missed this. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)